# Does this limit $\underset{x\to \pi }{\text{lim}}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos ^2(x)}}{\sin (x)} $ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to compute this limit
$$        \underset{x\to \pi }{\text{lim}}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos ^2(x)}}{\sin (x)}   $$
which is one of the indeterminate forms, $\frac00$; Using L'hopital, I get

$$        \underset{x\to \pi }{\text{lim}}\frac{\cos(x)\sin(x)}{\cos(x) \sqrt{1-\cos ^2(x) }}= \underset{x\to \pi }{\text{lim}}\frac{\sin(x)}{ \sqrt{1-\cos ^2(x)}}=\frac00    $$

which is again $\frac00$; then, does this mean that the limit does not exist? or there are other ways to compute such a limit that I am not aware of. I appreciate any comments.

Comment: Your function is undefined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ so your limit is undefined as well.

Comment: @bjorn93 But at $x=m \pi$, $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, the numerator and denominators are exactly zero.

Comment: And at every other value of $x$ close to but not equal to $m\pi$ ($m \in \mathbb Z$), the numerator is the square root of a negative number.

Comment: @math2021 true but irrelevant.  the limit of a function, as a specific element in the function's domain is approached has **nothing** to do with the value of the function at this element.  This is why the beginning of the definition of the limit is $$0 < |x - a| < \delta$$ rather than $$0 \leq |x - a| < \delta.$$

Comment: In *general* though, L’Hopital is one tool that usually works (if the limit exists, that is) in these trigonometric fraction limits, yes. Binomial expansion is another tool. Small angle approximations is another tool. And there are probably other tools you could use which I haven’t mentioned.

Comment: @LeeMosher And what happens if the sign of the argument in the square root changes? I mean if we have $1-(\cos x)^2$; in this case, it is defined.

Comment: You changed your question so much that the comments become incomprehensible. It would be more correct to write additions so that everyone can see what was and what has become. In the last option, you have the situation $\frac{|x|}{x}, x \to 0$.

Comment: There are cases when LH rule gives you an indeterminate form no matter how many times you apply, and the limit would still exist e.g. $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When l'Hopital's rule fails, you cannot make any conclusions. You must *try something else*.

Of course, why apply l'Hopital's rule at all, when you can use identities to simplify the problem?

With the edited version of your question, let's simplify first:
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}}{\sin(x)} = \frac{\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}}{\sin(x)} = \frac{|\sin(x)|}{\sin(x)} = \begin{cases}
+1 &\quad\text{if $0 < x < \pi$} \\
-1 &\quad\text{if $\pi < x < 2\pi$}
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, the limit as $x$ approaches $\pi$ from below equals $+1$ and the limit as $x$ approaches $\pi$ form above equals $-1$. So, the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

First note that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}}{\sin x} = \frac{\sqrt{\sin^2 x}}{\sin x} = \frac{\left|\sin x \right|}{\sin x }$$
whenever $\sin x \ne 0$.

We check the one-sided limits:
$$\lim_{x \to \pi^+} \frac{\left|\sin x \right|}{\sin x } = -1,$$

$$\lim_{x \to \pi^-} \frac{\left|\sin x \right|}{\sin x } = 1.$$

Therefore the limit $\lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x }}{\sin x }$ does not exist!